# How do you control two different objects separately(two player pong game)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

So I found this great game of pong created by this guy called Ferrari, and I was given the task to make it two playered with two scores but with no high score. I've tried many things except when I make a second bock of code that controls the movements it either gets completely ignored or I will press the up button that its assigned and it will go all the way up and won't come back down.

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
getcontext().prec = 20
import time,random,os,sys
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *
import tkFont
import os,sys

## decimal is for numbers and arithmatic that use irrational numbers
## Tkinter is the graphical interface for the program
## tkFont is the window that pops up
## os is operating system
## sys is system


## there are 2 different variables for player 1 and player 2 because one variable is a variable for a number, the other creates the rectangle(the actual paddle)
## these are just variables that represent numbers

refreshrate=100
do = 1
done=0
ballX=320
ballY=240
playerone=180
py2=180
pause=0
up=0
down=0
root = Tk()
root.title("Pong")
c = Canvas(root,width=640,height=480,bg='black')
c.pack()
xc = float(2)
yc = float(random.randint(-3,3))
while(yc==0):
    yc = float(random.randint(-3,3))
ball = c.create_oval(ballX-10,ballY-10,ballX+10,ballY+10,fill='white')
player = c.create_rectangle(610,playerone,625,playerone+120,fill='blue')
playertwo = c.create_rectangle(15,playerone,30,playerone+120,fill='blue')
c.create_rectangle(318,0,322,480,fill='white')
c.create_rectangle(318,0,322,30,fill='white')
score = 0
escore= 0
lives = 5
font = tkFont.Font(family = "Book Antiqua", size = 15, weight = "bold")

## to change the keys in which you press to control the paddles, change the letter or arrow key between the quotation marks next to str a   
## player1 controls

def up(event):
    global playerone, player, py2, playertwo, high, low
    up = 1
def down(event):
    global playerone, player, py2, playertwo, high, low
    down = 1
def escape(event):
    global do, lives
    lives = -1
    do = 0
    root.quit
    root.quit()
def onkeyrelease(event):
    global up, down, do, lives, pause
    key = event.keysym
    if (str(key)=="w"):
        up = 0
    if (str(key)=="s"):
        down = 0
    if (str(key)=="Escape" and done==1):
        root.quit
        do = 0
        lives = -1
        root.quit()
    if (str(key)=="p"):
        if(pause==1):
            pause=0
        elif(pause==0):
            pause=1
def buttoninit():
    root.bind("<w>",up)
    root.bind("<s>",down)
    root.bind("`",escape)
    root.bind('<KeyRelease>', onkeyrelease)
buttoninit()

## player2 controls

def high(event):
    global playerone, player, py2, playertwo, up, down
    up = 1
def low(event):
    global playerone, player, py2, playertwo, up, down
    down = 1
def leave(event):
    global do, lives
    lives = -1
    do = 0
    root.quit
    root.quit()
def offkeyrelease(event):
    global up, down, do, lives, pause
    key = event.keysym
    if (str(key)=="Up"):
        up = 0
    if (str(key)=="Down"):
        down = 0
    if (str(key)=="Escape" and done==1):
        root.quit
        do = 0
        lives = -1
        root.quit()
    if (str(key)=="p"):
        if(pause==1):
            pause=0
        elif(pause==0):
            pause=1
def buttononit():
    root.bind("<Up>",high)
    root.bind("<Down>",low)
    root.bind("`",leave)
    root.bind('<KeyRelease>', offkeyrelease)
buttononit()


c.create_text(475,10,text='Lives:',fill='white',font=font)
livestext = c.create_text(525,10,text=lives,fill='white',font=font)
c.create_text(475,25,text='Score:',fill='white',font=font)
scoretext = c.create_text(525,25,text=score,fill='white',font=font)
print "Push 'p' to pause"
var=1

while (do):
    ##  player movement controls
    if(playerone>0 and up==1 and down!=1 and pause==0):
        playerone=playerone-5
    if(playerone<360 and down==1 and up!=1 and pause==0):
        playerone=playerone+5

##  player collision detection
    if(ballX>=605 and ballY+10>=playerone and ballX<=616 and ballY+10>=playerone and ballY-10<=playerone+120):
        xc*=-1
        ballX=605
        if(xc>-10):
            xc=float(xc)-float(0.4)
        if(yc>0):
            yc=float(random.randint(15,70))
            yc=float(yc)/float(10)
        else: 
            yc=float(random.randint(-70,-15))
            yc=float(yc)/float(10)

##  playertwo movement controls
        if (playertwo>0 and high==1 and low!=1 and pause==0):
            playertwo=playertwo+5
        if (playertwo<360 and low==1 and high!=1 and pause==0):
            playertwo=playertwo-5

##  playertwo collision detection
    if(ballX<=40 and ballX>=29 and ballY+py2 and ballY-10<=py2+120):
        xc*=-1
        ballX=40
        if(xc<10):
            xc=float(xc)+float(0.4)
        if(yc>0):
            yc=float(random.randint(15,70))
            yc=float(yc)/float(10)
        else:
            yc=float(random.randint(-70,-15))
            yc=float(yc)/float(10)

##  left and right bounds collision detection (aka missed paddle)
    if(ballX>=630 and xc>0):
        ballX=320
        ballY=240
        xc = 2
        yc = random.randint(-3,3)
        while(yc==0):
            yc = random.randint(-3,3)
        lives = lives-1
        escore=escore+1
    if(ballX<=10 and xc<0):
        ballX=320
        ballY=240
        xc = 2
        yc = random.randint(-3,3)
        while(yc==0):
            yc = random.randint(-3,3)
        score=score+1

##  top and bottom bounds colliison detection
    if(playerone<0):
        playerone=0
    if(playerone>360):
        playerone=360
    if(ballY>=470 or ballY<=10):
        yc*=-1

##  AI(artificial intelligence(ball)) movement controls
    if(py2+60<ballY and py2<360 and xc<0 and pause==0):
        py2=py2+4
    if(py2+60>ballY and py2>0 and xc<0 and pause==0):
        py2=py2-4
    if(pause==0):
        ballX=ballX+xc
        ballY=ballY+yc
    c.delete(ball)
    ball = c.create_oval(ballX-10,ballY-10,ballX+10,ballY+10,fill='white')
    c.delete(player)
    player = c.create_rectangle(610,playerone,625,playerone+120,fill='blue')
    c.delete(playertwo)

# to change the game to single player, remove the playerone's in the following line and replace them with py2's
# this are  the coordinates for the paddle
# the first playerone, tracks the position of the thing that the paddle is following
# 1#= how wide it is, 2# tracks the other object, 3# the width, 4# how tall the paddle is, 5# the color

    playertwo = c.create_rectangle(15, playerone ,30,  playerone + 120 ,fill='blue')

    c.delete(livestext)
    livestext = c.create_text(525,10,text=lives,fill='white',font=font)
    c.delete(scoretext)
    scoretext = c.create_text(525,25,text=score,fill='white',font=font)
    c.update()
    time.sleep(Decimal("1")/Decimal("100"))
    if(lives==0):
        do=0
        if(score > 0):
            print score
        done = 1
    try:
        c.update()
    except:
        print "Error"
        root.quit
    while(lives==0):
        c.update()
try:
    c.update()
except:
    print "Error!!!"
    root.quit
```

Comment: I haven't investigated your code in any sort of thorough manner, but one issue that jumped out at me right away is that you're overwriting your `up` and `down` functions since those are also variable names. I'm not sure if it matters for their use as a callback, but it's probably something that should be fixed anyway. `do` is also a terrible variable name, even though it's not a keyword in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has been reworked into the following two-player game. The program has been reorganized into a variety of functions, classes, and methods. The controls are the same without an AI to play with.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font
import functools
import math
import random
import time; time.clock = time.perf_counter

################################################################################

class Pong(Canvas):

    DEFAULTS = dict(width=640,
                    height=480,
                    background='black',
                    highlightthickness=0)

    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        root = Tk()
        root.title('Pong')
        root.resizable(False, False)
        root.bind_all('<Escape>', lambda event: root.destroy())
        game = cls(Font(family='Book Antiqua', size=15, weight='bold'), 5, 100,
                   background='black', width=640, height=480)
        game.grid()
        root.mainloop()

    def __init__(self, font, lives, fps, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        for item in self.DEFAULTS.items():
            kw.setdefault(*item)
        super().__init__(master, cnf, **kw)
        self.font = font
        self.p1 = Paddle(lives, 'blue', 10,
                         self.height, 120, 15, 5)
        self.p2 = Paddle(lives, 'blue', self.width - 10,
                         self.height, 120, 15, 5)
        self.wait = 1000 // fps
        self.separator = Box(Point(self.width // 2 - 2, 0),
                             Point(self.width // 2 + 2, self.height))
        self.new_rect(self.separator, 'white')
        self.bind('<p>', self.pause)
        self.p1.bind(self, 'w', 's')
        self.p2.bind(self, 'Up', 'Down')
        self.draw_high = True
        self.after_idle(self.startup)
        self.focus_force()

    def pause(self, event):
        if not self.running_startup:
            self.refresh = self.after_cancel(self.refresh) \
                           if self.refresh else self.after_idle(self.animate)

    def startup(self, countdown=3, target=None):
        if target is None:
            self.running_startup = True
            self.ball = Ball('white', self.width, self.height, 20)
            self.refresh = None
            target = time.clock() + countdown
        for paddle in self.p1, self.p2:
            paddle.center()
        self.draw_all()
        remaining = math.ceil(target - time.clock())
        if remaining:
            self.new_text(Point(self.width >> 1, self.height >> 1),
                          self.random_color(), str(remaining), CENTER)
            self.after(self.wait, self.startup, None, target)
        else:
            self.running_startup = False
            self.after_idle(self.animate)

    @classmethod
    def random_color(cls):
        return '#{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}'.format(*cls.random_bytes(3))

    @staticmethod
    def random_bytes(n):
        return bytes(random.randrange(1 << 8) for _ in range(n))

    def animate(self):
        self.move_all()
        if self.in_bounds():
            self.draw_all()
            self.refresh = self.after(self.wait, self.animate)

    def move_all(self):
        for obj in self.p1, self.p2, self.ball:
            obj.move()
            if obj is not self.ball:
                obj.bounce(self.ball)

    def in_bounds(self):
        if self.boundary.intersects(self.ball.boundary):
            return True
        if (self.p2 if self.ball.position.x > 0 else self.p1).kill():
            self.after_idle(self.startup)
        else:
            self.draw_all()
            self.after(5000, self.quit)
        return False

    def draw_all(self):
        self.delete('actor')
        for obj in self.p1, self.p2, self.ball:
            obj.render(self)
        self.render_status()

    def render_status(self, x_margin=4, y_margin=4):
        self.draw_high = high = (self.ball.position.y > self.height * 0.25) \
                                if self.draw_high else \
                                (self.ball.position.y >= self.height * 0.75)
        if high:
            self.new_text(self.separator.NW + Point(-x_margin, +y_margin),
                          'white', self.p1.status, NE)
            self.new_text(self.separator.NE + Point(+x_margin, +y_margin),
                          'white', self.p2.status, NW)
        else:
            self.new_text(self.separator.SW + Point(-x_margin, -y_margin),
                          'white', self.p1.status, SE)
            self.new_text(self.separator.SE + Point(+x_margin, -y_margin),
                          'white', self.p2.status, SW)

    def new_rect(self, box, color, tag='static'):
        self.create_rectangle(box, fill=color, outline=color, tag=tag)

    def new_oval(self, box, color, tag='static'):
        self.create_oval(box, fill=color, outline=color, tag=tag)

    def new_text(self, point, color, text, anchor, tag='actor'):
        self.create_text(point, fill=color, tag=tag,
                         text=text, anchor=anchor, font=self.font)

    @property
    def width(self):
        return int(self['width'])

    @property
    def height(self):
        return int(self['height'])

    @property
    def boundary(self):
        return Box(Point(0, 0), Point(self.width, self.height))

################################################################################

def enum(names):
    return type('enum', (), dict(map(reversed, enumerate(
        names.replace(',', ' ').split())), __slots__=()))()

def copy_sign(x, y):
    return type(x)(math.copysign(x, y))

################################################################################

class Paddle:

    PART = enum('null, upper, center, lower')

    def __init__(self, lives, color, alignment, board_height,
                 paddle_height, paddle_width, move_by):
        self.lives = lives
        self.color = color
        self.height = board_height
        self.position = Point(alignment, board_height >> 1)
        self.size = Point(paddle_width >> 1, paddle_height >> 1)
        self.move_by = move_by
        self.score = 0
        self.just_bounced = False

    def kill(self):
        self.lives -= 1
        self.score >>= 1
        return self.lives > 0

    def center(self):
        y, middle = self.position.y, self.height >> 1
        if y < middle:
            self.move(down=True)
        elif y > middle:
            self.move(up=True)

    def move(self, *, up=False, down=False):
        if up or (not down and self.keys.up and
                  self.position.y - self.size.y > 0):
            self.position -= Point(0, self.move_by)
        if down or (not up and self.keys.down and
                    self.position.y + self.size.y < self.height):
            self.position += Point(0, self.move_by)

    def bounce(self, ball):
        minimum = self.size.x + ball.radius
        if self.position.x != ball.position.x and self.overlap(ball, minimum):
            if not self.just_bounced:
                self.just_bounced = True
                self.score += abs(ball.velocity.y)
            sign = +1 if self.position.x < ball.position.x else -1
            if self.collision_area == self.PART.center:
                ball.position.x = self.position.x + minimum * sign
            else:
                ball.position.adjust(self.middle_point, minimum)
            ball.velocity.x = copy_sign(ball.velocity.x, sign)
            ball.change_speed()
        else:
            self.just_bounced = False

    def overlap(self, ball, minimum):
        box = self.boundary
        if box.intersects(ball.boundary):
            self.collision_area = self.PART.center
        elif (self.hi_mid(box) - ball.position).magnitude <= minimum:
            self.collision_area = self.PART.upper
        elif (self.lo_mid(box) - ball.position).magnitude <= minimum:
            self.collision_area = self.PART.lower
        else:
            self.collision_area = self.PART.null
        return self.collision_area

    def render(self, surface):
        box = self.boundary
        surface.new_rect(box, self.color, 'actor')
        surface.new_oval(Box.from_point(self.hi_mid(box), self.size.x),
                         self.color, 'actor')
        surface.new_oval(Box.from_point(self.lo_mid(box), self.size.x),
                         self.color, 'actor')

    def hi_mid(self, boundary):
        self.middle_point = Point(self.position.x, boundary.a.y)
        return self.middle_point

    def lo_mid(self, boundary):
        self.middle_point = Point(self.position.x, boundary.b.y)
        return self.middle_point

    def bind(self, surface, up, down):
        self.keys = KeyListener(surface, up=up, down=down)

    @property
    def boundary(self):
        return Box.from_point(self.position, self.size)

    @property
    def status(self):
        return 'Lives: {}\nScore: {}'.format(self.lives, self.score)

Player = Paddle

################################################################################

class KeyListener:

    def __init__(self, widget, **kwargs):
        self.__state = dict.fromkeys(kwargs, False)
        for name, key in kwargs.items():
            widget.bind('<KeyPress-{}>'.format(key), self.__set(name, True))
            widget.bind('<KeyRelease-{}>'.format(key), self.__set(name, False))

    def __set(self, name, value):
        def handler(event):
            self.__state[name] = value
        return handler

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.__state[name]

################################################################################

class Ball:

    def __init__(self, color, width, height, size):
        self.color = color
        self.board = Point(width, height)
        self.position = self.board / 2
        self.radius = size >> 1
        self.velocity = Point(1 - 2 * random.randrange(2),
                              1 - 2 * random.randrange(2))
        self.change_speed()

    def change_speed(self, max_x=10, max_y=10):
        speed = self.velocity
        speed.x = copy_sign(random.randint(1, max_x), speed.x)
        speed.y = copy_sign(random.randint(1, max_y), speed.y)

    def move(self):
        self.position += self.velocity
        self.bounce()

    def bounce(self):
        if self.position.y - self.radius < 0:
            self.position.y = self.radius
            self.velocity.y = copy_sign(self.velocity.y, +1)
            self.change_speed()
        elif self.position.y + self.radius > self.board.y:
            self.position.y = self.board.y - self.radius
            self.velocity.y = copy_sign(self.velocity.y, -1)
            self.change_speed()

    def render(self, surface):
        surface.new_oval(self.boundary, self.color, 'actor')

    @property
    def boundary(self):
        return Box.from_point(self.position, self.radius)

################################################################################

def autocast(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def cast(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            other = self.__class__(other, other)
        return function(self, other)
    return cast

################################################################################

class Point(list):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__((x, y))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({})'.format(self.__class__.__name__,
                               ', '.join(map(repr, self)))

    @autocast
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    @autocast
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

    @autocast
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(self.x * other.x, self.y * other.y)

    @autocast
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(self.x / other.x, self.y / other.y)

    @autocast
    def __floordiv__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(self.x // other.x, self.y // other.y)

    @autocast
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.x += other.x
        self.y += other.y
        return self

    @autocast
    def __isub__(self, other):
        self.x -= other.x
        self.y -= other.y
        return self

    def __get_x(self):
        return self[0]

    def __set_x(self, value):
        self[0] = value

    x = property(__get_x, __set_x)

    def __get_y(self):
        return self[1]

    def __set_y(self, value):
        self[1] = value

    y = property(__get_y, __set_y)

    def __get_magnitude(self):
        return math.hypot(self.x, self.y)

    def __set_magnitude(self, value):
        magnitude = self.magnitude
        self.x *= value / magnitude
        self.y *= value / magnitude

    magnitude = property(__get_magnitude, __set_magnitude)

    def adjust(self, projected_from, distance):
        vector = self - projected_from
        vector.magnitude = distance
        self.x = round(projected_from.x + vector.x)
        self.y = round(projected_from.y + vector.y)

################################################################################

class Box(list):

    @classmethod
    def from_point(cls, point, extension):
        return cls(point - extension, point + extension)

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__((a, b))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({})'.format(self.__class__.__name__,
                               ', '.join(map(repr, self)))

    def intersects(self, other):
        return not (self.a.x > other.b.x or other.a.x > self.b.x or
                    self.a.y > other.b.y or other.a.y > self.b.y)

    def __get_a(self):
        return self[0]

    def __set_a(self, value):
        self[0] = value

    a = NW = property(__get_a, __set_a)

    def __get_b(self):
        return self[1]

    def __set_b(self, value):
        self[1] = value

    b = SE = property(__get_b, __set_b)

    @property
    def NE(self):
        return Point(self.b.x, self.a.y)

    @property
    def SW(self):
        return Point(self.a.x, self.b.y)

################################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Pong.main()
```

**Edit:** In designing the scoring system, it did not make sense to have a score and lives. If a player's score is incremented by one when the opponent looses, scores could be dropped, and the winner would be the person who did not loose all lives. If a player's score is incremented by one each time the ball is hit, both players will have nearly identical scores throughout the game, and the scores are fairly meaningless.

I chose to increment a player's score based on an approximation of how difficult the ball was to hit. If the ball happened to have a vertical movement of five and the player hits the ball, then the player's score is incremented by five. To add further incentive not to loose lives, a player's score is halved upon loosing a life. That also provides ample opportunity for the other player to catch up in scoring.

As for the weird bouncing, the ball will have a random change in speed each time it hits an object. The reason for this is that if the ball stayed at the same speed and bounced normally, it would be very easy to predict where the ball was going to go, and the game would be too easy. If the player finds no challenge in the game, being bored and invincible would lead to rapid abandonment of the game.

The status display moves to the opposite side of the board when the ball gets close enough so that the status and ball never end up on top of each other, confusing potential players. The change is triggered by the ball's moving up past 25% screen height or the ball's moving down past 75% screen height. If there is anything that you feel should be different about the game, please consider learning Python so that you can modify the game yourself.

Comment: you should have commented it, no way he is going to understand that

Comment: After I fixed he importing errors, it gave me Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled", line 435
    Pong.main()
  File "Untitled", line 24, in main
    backgound='black', width=640, height=480)
  File "Untitled", line 31, in __init__
    super().__init__(master, cnf, **kw)
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)               And I don't know what it means or how to fix it.

Comment: Try running the code with the latest version of Python (3.2.3), and you should not need to make any changes to get it working.

Comment: That's sick but the score and lives move up and down, and it gets messed up after like a minute the score was like 33 to 14, and the last complaint sorry, is that the direction of the ball after it hits one of the side is not the exact opposite, like if it hits the side it does all this crazy movements. But thanks for the help its sick.

Comment: Hopefully, the explanation added after the code in the edit will explain some of the game's bizarre behavior. I wanted to write Pong according to your code but also add my own design that would set it apart from other implementations.